# cfif statement with no expression or conditionals

Tags: coldfusion

Took over some code and I found this logic:

```
<cfif FALSE>
execute this code
<cfelse>
execute this
</cfif>
```

There is no conditional or expresssion for the IF statement.  Just hanging out there as 'FALSE'.  What is this statement evaluating then? OR What is the default expression of a cfif statement?

Comment: `FALSE` *is* a legit boolean expression.

Comment: Sometimes the best thing is to try yourself. Take that code out and run it on a 'debug' or test page, see for yourself what it does. Other people will help you but it does not compare with finding out the answer by yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That example will always run the "execute this" bit (the cfelse). The "execute this code" bit will never run. Looks like an odd way of preventing a chunk of old code from running. The "execute this code" bit could've just been commented-out or removed (and thus no need for the cfif/cfelse tags).

Comment: That is exactly what i was thinking!  It seems really odd and I wanted to make sure i wasn't 'missing' something.    Thank you for another set of eyes on this.

Comment: When I find code like this I assume debugging or exceptional use. Sometimes a specific action (updating a db or fixing something in a file) might be required one time - or perhaps from time to time. The dev can come in and change it it to TRUE, run it, then change it back. It's bad practice but it works (as long as you are a one man team with no SDLC to speak of. :)

Comment: Maybe it was written for debugging purposes and the developer forgot to change it back to the real test.  I've made similar mistakes.

Comment: YVW Tom and very good points (hadn't considered those) Mark and Dan :)